# Mask blocking Flash content in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I know your not really supposed to use Flash and SWF's in a Sencha Touch project. But im using it in a project where we're just gonna use the HTML5 Web app in Chrome.

http://kachipun.se/sandbox/touch/

Now the problem i have is that im using a Slide in menu, much like the one Facebook uses in their app. And when you click the upper left corner to show the menu, ah semi-transparent mask is put over the main content. Now, under the second menu item in the list i have a tabPanel with a SWF. This SWF is not interact-able now since theres a invincible mask laying over the main panel. But the funny thing is that all of the hovering effects in the SWF are working as intended, you just cant advance by clicking..

So how do i get rid of this mask without breaking the menu, or is it a way for me to bring the main panel forth and over the mask? I've tried all sorts of z-index hacks, but nothing seems to work!

I hope that i've made myself clear and i appreciate all the help i can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the mask manually.

If it is in the viewport, use:

```
Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
```

If it is in a container with id my-id use:

```
Ext.getCmp('my-id').setMasked(false);
```